# Selenium autoscroll

Tags: javascript, selenium, autoscroll

I'm new to using Selenium so I would like to have some help regarding these questions.

1) How to automate scrolling and let it stop once it reaches the height of the desktop? As I want to screenshot a webpage based on its full screen, I want it to be able to autoscroll to a certain desktop height, take a screenshot, continue scrolling to the next same height, take a screenshot again till the end of page.

2) How do you determine the end of a page? By using JavaScript's scrollTo method or is there any other ways?

Comment: Depending on the browser, the screenshot already takes the whole page (not just the viewport). What WebDriver are you using?

Comment: I'm using Selenium WebDriver. @acdcjunior

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: I meant what browser: FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, PhantomJSDriver...

Comment: FirefoxDriver. @acdcjunior

Answer (score 0):

You may try to scroll by defining `x` and `y` axis. Try this code for javascript

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");`

Let me know if this helps.